# iOS 15 UIButton configuration - how to write a closure for configuration handler

Tags: ios, swift, ios15

Following a tutorial I am using a the new UIButtons and iOS 15.

```
    let btn = UIButton(frame:CGRect(x: 25, y:0 , width: 250, height: 50))
    btn.config.title = "Connect"
    btn.updateConfiguration()
    btn.configurationUpdateHandler = { button in
      var config = btn.configuration
        switch button.state {
        case .highlighted:
            config?.showsActivityIndicator = true
            config?.imagePadding = 5
            self.role = self.nameInput.text?.lowercased()
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.role, forKey: "role")
            SFSConn.shared.connect()
        default:
            config?.showsActivityIndicator = false
        }
      btn.configuration = config
    }
    btnForm.addSubview(btn)
```

How can I extrapolate the closure into a stand-alone closure?
I'd like to connect multiple buttons to the same closure.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `configurationUpdateHandler` property is of type `UIButton.ConfigurationUpdateHandler?`, which is just a typealias for `(UIButton) -> Void`, which is a closure that takes a single parameter of `UIButton`. So just create that.

```
let handler: (UIButton) -> Void = { (button) in
    // do something
}

btn.configurationUpdateHandler = handler
```

Comment: Thank you. In the handler, it says I can't use self.role. Do I need to pass it [weak self]?

Comment: @dreadbot if you want to use `self` in an instance property of an object, that property must be lazy (which just means that it won't actually be initialized until it is first accessed) because the object has to initialize itself before `self` can become available and part of initializing itself requires initializing all of its properties. You can see how this would create an infinite loop. So just declare it as a lazy property with the syntax `lazy var handler` instead of `let handler`.

Comment: @dreadbot you can still make `self` weak with `[weak self] (button) in` in the closure's capture list if you need to, in addition to making the closure itself lazy. Just remember that weak self is to prevent retain cycles. If `self` (i.e. a view controller) would ever be `nil` before some async work in this closure finishes, for example, then definitely declare self weak.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. Is there a way in the button config to make it disabled? I'm trying to create an interface where a selection of 1 button disables 3 others.

Comment: @dreadbot you can disable the button's user interactivity with `btn.isUserInteractionEnabled = false`. This won't change the button's styling, however--is that what you want??

Comment: Thanks, that's how I normally do it. What will trigger the button.state .disabled so I can use my configHandler to style it when it becomes disabled?

Comment: Figured it out. It's btn.isEnabled = false. That triggers the disabled state in the configHandler.